# Why does formatting get all funky when returning more than one string?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to write a script that will return the results of elections throughout the years for my congressional district.  I've written the code that will give me the most recent election's results (2014), and when I run the code it gives me the info in a properly formatted manner:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

# load the right wiki page [24th congress. district]
html = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York\'s_24th_congressional_district')
# make it soupy
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "lxml")

def electionResults(link):
    biggross = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable'})
    results2014 = biggross.find_next('table',{'class':'wikitable'})
    results2014text = results2014.text
    results2012 = results2014.find_next('table',{'class':'wikitable'})
    results2012text = results2012.text
    return results2014text

print(electionResults(soup))
```

Output looks like this:

```
US House election, 2014: New York District 24, 99.67% reporting

Party
Candidate
Votes
%
±%
Republican
John Katko
112,469
59.9
+16.6
Democratic
Dan Maffei
75,286
40.1
-7.6
Majority
37,183
19.8
+14.4
Turnout
187,755
100
-30.2
```

(cut out some spaces and new lines for sake of the length of the post.)

However, when I change the last line of the function to `return results2014text,results2012text`, I get an output that looks like this:

```
('\n\nUS House election, 2014: New York District 24, 99.67% reporting\n\n\nParty\nCandidate\nVotes\n%\n±%\n\n\n\nRepublican\nJohn Katko\n112,469\n59.9\n+16.6\n\n\n\nDemocratic\nDan Maffei\n75,286\n40.1\n-7.6\n\n\nMajority\n37,183\n19.8\n+14.4\n\n\nTurnout\n187,755\n100\n-30.2\n\n', 'US House election, 2012: New York District 24, 99% reporting\n\n\nParty\nCandidate\nVotes\n%\n±%\n\n\n\nDemocratic\nDan Maffei\n131,242\n48.7\n-1.1\n\n\n\nRepublican\nAnn Marie Buerkle\n116,641\n43.3\n-6.9\n\n\n\nGreen\nUrsula Rozum\n21,413\n8.0\n+8.0\n\n\nMajority\n14,601\n5.4\n+5.0\n\n\nTurnout\n269,296\n100\n+29.4')
```

How can I preserve the (relatively) workable formatting that the function spits back when I only have it return the results for 2014 when changing it to return more than one election's results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to return two variables at once, by calling `return results2014text,results2012text`, Python is taking the two variables and creating a sequence of the two, much like a list. So instead, when you call `print(electionResults(soup))`, you're printing a tuple object, not a string.

If you want it to print both objects, change the print statement to:

```
for results in electionResults(soup):
    print results
```

Answer (score 1):

Returning multiple values is equivalent to returning a tuple.

When you print a value, it prints str(value). When calling str on a tuple, for the items in the tuple str(item) is not called, but rather repr(item). This means that strings will have quotes around them, for instance. In the case of beautifulsoup this returns something less helpful.

If you want to preserve the formatting, you could convert each item in the tuple to a string.

Answer (score 1):

`return results2014text, results2012text` means you are returning a tuple and to print the tuple like the way you want, we've to do something like

```
result = electionResults(soup)
print result[0] + '\n' + result[1]
```